# minimal number of edges for a graph of size N so that there are two paths between any pair of nodes

Tags: graph-theory, network

I am trying to figure out how many edges are nessisary in a graph of size n so that between any two nodes in the graphs, there are two path that differ by at least one edges connecting them. (I allow for multiple independent edges between two nodes)

Comment: Two possible interpretations: 1) give a graph with the minimum number of edges with the property that any two nodes are connected by two different paths (an obvious choice is a cycle). 2) what is the minimum $e$ such that any graph on $n$ vertices and $e$ edges has the property that any two nodes are connected by two different paths (here, the allowance of multiple edges ensures there is no such $e$).